# When configuring RetryOnFailure what is the maxRetryDelay parameter

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm using Entity Framework Core 2.2 and i decided to follow some blog sugestion and enable retry on failure:

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>( options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(Configurations["ConnectionString"]),
    sqlServerOptionsAction: sqlOptions =>
    {
        sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(
        maxRetryCount: 10,
        maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
        errorNumbersToAdd: null);
    });
```

My question is what is the `maxRetryDelay` argument for?
I would expect it to be the delay time between retries, but the name implies its the maximum time, does that mean i can do my 10 retries 1 second apart and not 5 seconds apart as i desire?

Comment: Imagine 10K requests failing at the same time. Do you want to hammer the server with 10K retries after 5 seconds? Or would you rather have them spread across? What if the retries fail 1 or 2 times, do you want to use the *same* retry delay? Or would you rather wait a bit longer the second or third time?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The delay between retries [is randomized](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/43f040f510450cb4ba25e4690b0ddac88e1019ee/src/EFCore/Storage/ExecutionStrategy.cs#L341) up to the value specified by `maxRetryDelay`.

This is done to avoid multiple retries occuring at the same time and overwhelming a server. Imagine for example 10K requests to a web service failing due to a network issue and retrying at the same time after 15 seconds. The database server would get a sudden wave of 15K queries.

By randomizing the delay, retries are spread across time and client.

The delay for each retry is calculated by [ExecutionStragegy.GetNextDelay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.storage.executionstrategy.getnextdelay?view=efcore-2.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Storage_ExecutionStrategy_GetNextDelay_System_Exception_). The [source](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/43f040f510450cb4ba25e4690b0ddac88e1019ee/src/EFCore/Storage/ExecutionStrategy.cs#L341) shows it's a random exponential backoff.

The default [SqlServerRetryingExecutionStrategy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverretryingexecutionstrategy?view=efcore-2.1) uses that implementation. A custom retry strategy could use a different implementation